# Is it possible to use multiple compute buffers in compute shader in HLSL in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl, marching-cubes

Is there any way to use two buffers in compute shader in HLSL in Unity? I need to use one to input some scalar values on a grid and one to get back vertex array generated by marching cubes.

Comment: I used multiple `StructuredBuffer<float4>` and it works just fine. Without further details I'd expect no problems.

Comment: @KYL3R but how do I know which buffer do I pass data to? and which buffer do i get data from?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a RWStructuredBuffer - `RW` means `Read`+`Write`
A normal `StructuredBuffer` is write-protected: you can't write TO it from the shader, but read it after passing it from C#.

You can define multiple in shader:

```
RWStructuredBuffer<float4> myFirstBuffer : register(u1); // index1 !
RWStructuredBuffer<float4> mySecondBuffer : register(u2); // index2 !
```

And access them like this in C#:

```
Graphics.ClearRandomWriteTargets();
material.SetPass(0);
material.SetBuffer("myFirstBuffer", myFirstBuffer);
Graphics.SetRandomWriteTarget(1, myFirstBuffer, false); // index 1!
compute_buffer.GetData(myFirstBuffer);

material.SetBuffer("mySecondBuffer", mySecondBuffer);
Graphics.SetRandomWriteTarget(2, mySecondBuffer, false); // index 2!
compute_buffer.GetData(mySecondBuffer);
```

Comment: Is specyfying material really needed when using compute shader?

Comment: I didn't test the code, but it should give you an idea. You will find out the rest :)